# Javascript: I need to prompt a visitor for three things and then list them with a "for loop"

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need to prompt a visitor for three things and then list them with a "for loop" and the HTML `<ol>` and `<li>`

This is what I have, but it doesn't work:

```
<script>

var favbook1 = prompt("What is your favotire first book?", "");
var favbook2 = prompt("What is your favotire second book?", "");
var favbook3 = prompt("What is your favotire third book?", "");

books[0] = favbook1;
books[1] = favbook2;
books[2] = favbook3;

for (var i = 0; i < books.lenght ; i++) {
  document.write(books[i] , "<br>")
}

</script>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's `length` not `lenght` and you haven't defined `books`

Comment: I suggest you try an learn how to work the debugging tools, most browsers have good tools these days.

Comment: always check the console for error messages. there you would have seen that `books` is `undefined` and not an array (if that is you whole code).

Comment: @pst `books[0] = ... ` will be an error if `books` is `undefined`

Comment: What should I change in the script above to get a result?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to prompt a visitor for three things and then list them with a
>   `for loop` and the HTML `<ol>` and `<li>`

You have to declare `books` first before you can assign values to it and you have a typo in `lenght` which should be `.length` instead.

Your code also does not create an `ol` with `li` elements. If that is what you wanted you can do something similar to this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var books = [];

    var favbook1 = prompt("What is your favotire first book?", "");
    var favbook2 = prompt("What is your favotire second book?", "");
    var favbook3 = prompt("What is your favotire third book?", "");

    books.push(favbook1);
    books.push(favbook2);
    books.push(favbook3);

    var myList = document.createElement("ol");
    var myListItem;

    for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        myListItem = document.createElement("li");
        myListItem.innerHTML = books[i];
        myList.appendChild(myListItem);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(myList);
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rafum/) - Create `ol` with `li` for each book

---

Answer (score 1):

It should be

`for (var i = 0; i < books.length ; i++) {`

EDIT: You should also declare books as an array before the books[0]... line:

`var books = new Array();`

Also it should be:

`document.write(books[i] + "<br />");`

Comment: Thank you for your answers: 
I changed to " for (var i = 0; i < books.length ; i++) { " -> doesn't work ...

Comment: @Artem "doesn't work" isn't a good way of describing a problem to another developer.

Comment: @Artem: remove the `,` in the document.write and put a `+` there

Comment: @vol7ron `document.write` accepts a variable list of parameters that will concatenated.

Comment: @t.niese: that's failed before, but I admit I haven't used document.write in years.